# How can I backup my apps, ppas, firefox bookmarks, fonts, icon sets, webcam drivers before a clean install?

Tags: 11.10, installation, backup

So I've fine-tuned my Natty with different icon sets, themes, fonts from sites I don't remember now. And there are these apps, ppas which are very difficult to find, add again. So how do I backup everything and restore ? How different will an upgrade be from a clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have a different partition for /home things are a lot easier.

1-)fonts, themes, icons, firefox bookmarks are all in your home folder
2-)ppas, apps and drivers are in / partition so you need to save them in some other way

Start the installation and choose advanced partition or something like thta. In your existing /home set up a mount point for /home and DON'T select to format it, then choose another partition for / and format it.

When the installation finish you can restart and you will have your theme, fonts, settings, account and documents like before.

For apps you can use OneConf which is avalaible in the software center and preinstalled in oneiric

For driver and ppas i don't know

Comment: Can you explain it in detail ? I do have a different partition for /home.

Comment: i've edited my answer, tell me if you need something else!

Comment: Okay, I've this system now for beta2. But I've two systems of home folders in my /home partition under different usernames. What should I do? And for PPAs I found out Y-PPA manager can do backup/restore. Driver I will install again.

Comment: if you upgrade your beta 2 you will get the current stable but if you have two username i suggest you to delete one of them and then reinstall using the same home and remembering to use the same username to avoid having two different users like now

Comment: If I use the same username, won't it rewrite the previous data ?

Comment: no it will only add nw data if avalaible but nothing will be replaced

Answer (score 0):

Use partimage or fsarchiver to archive the whole partition. In case you don't like oneiric you can restore the whole partition very quickly. These programs are part of [SystemRescueCd](http://sysresccd.org/Main_Page).

Comment: I like Oneiric, I've installed beta2 in another partition. Now I want to replace Natty with Oneric and retain everything.